# Is it a good practice to compare responses with benchmark responses in API Test Automation?

Tags: api-testing, rest-api, rest, rest-assured

Is it is good practice while writing automated tests for APIs to compare the complete response of the requests with a benchmark response instead of writing specific tests to verify the required values ? 
What if there are too many values to verify ? Is there any clean and optimized way to do the same ?

Please share thoughts so that I may know about the best standard followed industry wide.

Comment: What's the difference between comparing complete response to individual values ? if the benchmark response was built with common sense while being aware of its content then it's simply a more efficient way for comparison.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the service.  If I'm testing something that doesn't change, or doesn't change often, I would assert the response against a benchmark response.

For those services where the data may change, I would look to write some sort of validation script to compare the response results with the db.

Comment: Thanks for the insights Chris